# VGA Monitor is listed as a DisplayPort monitor and only resolution is 640x480

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, vga

I have dual monitor setup for my development workflow but I recently installed ubuntu 20.04 and hooked up a vga monitor hanging around. There are couple of problems with it.
Firstly, monitor shows as unknown display in "Displays" and only resolution listed is 640x480. The result of "xrandr --listactivemonitors"

```
Monitors: 3
0: +*HDMI-A-0 2560/798x1080/334+0+0  HDMI-A-0
1: +DVI-D-0 1920/480x1080/270+2560+0  DVI-D-0
2: +DisplayPort-0 640/169x480/127+4480+0  DisplayPort-0
```

As you've seen monitor with index "2" is actually connected to VGA port but lists as DisplayPort monitor.I use cpu graphics on Ryzen 2400g. Graphics driver is stock ubuntu(20.04) amdgpu open source driver. VGA monitor model is LG E1951S-BN with native resolution of 1366x768.
So, how can i make this monitor run at native resolution?